# Connection between Stochastic Neighbor Embedding and MDS

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, multidimensional-scaling, tsne

In the original [SNE paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2276-stochastic-neighbor-embedding.pdf) the authors mention a connection between the SNE objective function and an MDS-like stress function in the regime $\sigma_i \rightarrow \infty$, as follows.

> When $\sigma_i^2$ is very large, it can be shown that SNE is equivalent to minimizing the mismatch between squared distances in the two spaces, provided all the squared distances from an object $i$ are first normalized by subtracting off their antigeometric mean $g_i^2$:
>   $$\textrm{Mismatch} = \sum_{ij} \big[(d_{ij}^2 - g_i^2) - (\hat{d}_{ij}^2 - \hat{g}_i^2) \big]^2$$ with $$d_{ij}^2 = \lVert x_i - x_j \rVert^2 / \sigma^2,\quad g_i^2 = -\log \sum_{k \ne i} \frac{\exp(-d_{ij}^2)}{n -1}$$ and $\hat{d}_{ij}^2$ and $\hat{g}_i^2$ defined similarly for the embedding points $\{y_i\}$.

My question is, **how exactly is this mismatch function derived and what does it represent**?

It seems strange because they say "when $\sigma_i^2$ is very large" so one might expect that they're talking about a limit, but then there's still a $\sigma$ in the expression obtained. Also, for $\sigma_i = \sigma$ constant, the expression inside the brackets is exactly $-\log(p_{ij}) + \log(q_{ij})$ and I don't see where the square could come from. What is going on here?

Comment: +1. I wondered about it too. I like how they use "it can be shown" here :)

Comment: It cannot be the actual limit, because in the limit all p_i's are equal and the loss is minimized when all points in the embedding are infinitely far away from each other (to make q's equal to 0).

Comment: Not infinitely far away, but uniformly distributed. In the limit, only the entropy part of the KL divergence remains, which is maximized when the distribution is uniform.

Comment: Why? If all p's are equal, then the loss function is simpy \sum\log(q) up to a constant factor, and this is minimized when points are infinitely far away from each other.

Comment: $\mathrm{D}_{\textrm{KL}} [ p_i \parallel q_i ] = -\log(n - 1) - \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{j = 1}^n \log q_{ij}$, with $\lim_{\sigma \to \infty} p_{ij} = \frac{1}{n - 1}$, so minimizing the KL divergence corresponds to maximizing the term you mentioned.  It's not the entropy, as I said above (I was thinking about the exclusive formulation of the KL divergence), but it's still maximized when $q_i$ is the uniform distribution. This is also intuitive: you match an uniform distribution with another uniform one.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform"? \sum\log(q) is minimized when all q go to 0. This happens when all distances go to infinity. Only then will q's be the same. If the distances are finite, q's will be unequal.

Comment: But that term has to be maximized for the KL divergence to be minimized, as I've shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Right, I forgot the minus :-/ Thanks. You are right that the loss is minimized when all q's are equal to each other, because of course they need to match the p's that are equal. But this is impossible to achieve in 2D. Not sure how the optimal 2D configuration actually looks like... Anyway, this was a digression from your actual question :)